# Make a Google Map using Lat and Long coords

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have looked around and found various geocoding examples using Googles API and I am now stuck.

I have used Google API to convert a postcode into longitude and latitude coordinates, but now I want a Google map that uses those coordinates and the postcode to show a marker and then place the map on my site. Exactly the same as the iframe that you can get from the google maps site :

For example this :

Link of [Google Map](https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=CT2%200QF&hl=en&sll=53.800651,-4.064941&sspn=13.440126,37.836914&hnear=Canterbury%20CT2,%20United%20Kingdom&t=m&z=12).

My site will go load the `lat` and long from my `MySQL` database and then place them into a link but just no luck!

Any ideas?

Comment: are you using javascript? googlemaps v3 i suppose?

Comment: Have you tried any tutorials? This is very basic google maps functionality and there are plenty of tutorials on the other end of a Google search :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetch the `$postadress`, `lat` and `long` value from database and then you these values like ,

```
 <script  type="text/javascript">
     var locations = [['$postaddress ;','$lat;', ' $long;', '1'],];
 </script>

 <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <div id="map" class="googlemapimage"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom:15,  
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat;?>, <?php echo $long; ?>),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }

      })(marker, i));
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {

          infowindow.close();
        }

      })(marker, i));
       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
           infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }

      })(marker, i));
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Its basically js script to show google map...so use var locations = [['<?php $postaddress ; ?>','<?php $lat; ?>', '<?php $long ?>;', '1'], ];

Comment: Did exactly as you have said, replacing all the parts with my variables and still no luck :/

Comment: Can't paste my code here either :/  >>
 var locations = [['<?php $pcode; ?>','<?php $lat; ?>', '<?php $lng; ?>', '1']];

Changed all other references of pcode and lng aswell to those.

Comment: Do one thing...Just place the static lat log in the script and then check whether it is showing the map or not..

Comment: make sure there is no js error because its working fine here http://beta-demo.info/party/event/eventdetail/11620

Comment: Seems to be an issue about my PHP ... I use a while loop to pull all the stuff from the db, and it works for everything except the those details, unless I place the PHP at the end however I need to pull the details early on to put them in the script :/

Comment: using the css you can increase the width...#map{width:500px;flolt:left}

Comment: http://beta-demo.info/party/event/eventdetail/11620 Here i make a class to maintain the height and width of the map...

Comment: Your link doesn't work for me : 
The event which you want to access is either out of date or not a valid.

Answer (score 2):

The Google Map isn't an iframe there, its a bunch of divs with different map tiles positioned here and there.

If you're using the Google Maps API v3, just look at the source code of [this google example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple). It should be exactly what you need. It's pretty simple.

Basically, you initialize the map on a central lng/lat. In that example, it centres it and adds a marker (which presumably is what you're after).

Alternatively, if you only need a picture/marker, and no interactivity, you can see the Static Maps API. It's just like loading an image (you just pass in the long/lat to the img src attribute: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Comment: That map doesn't seem to like my coding .. which is unfortunate but plus one anyway ~D